# Is there a way to flatten or merge single-folder folders in vs code explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know if there's a name for this kind of behavior.
I've seen it in IntelliJ, where single-folder folders are unified or flattened in the project tree pane, where instead of:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── somepkg
│   │   │           └── coreapi
│   │   │               ├── controllers
│   │   │               │   ├── AssetMutations.java
│   │   │               │   ├── HomeController.java
│   │   │               │   └── SessionsQuery.java
│   │   │               ├── CoreApiApplication.java
```

You see:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com.somepkg.coreapi
│   │   │       ├── controllers
│   │   │       │   ├── AssetMutations.java
│   │   │       │   ├── HomeController.java
│   │   │       │   └── SessionsQuery.java
│   │   │       ├── CoreApiApplication.java
```

Is there a way to make vs code tree-view file explorer to show subfolders this way?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It looks like it is in the iteration plan for June, 2019.

See [Iteration plan for June, 2019: release in July, 2019](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75103) and [issue: merging single child directories](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41627).

---

Update: making it into v1.41 to be released in December, 2019.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#compact-folders-in-explorer

> **Compact folders in Explorer**
>
> In the File Explorer, we now render single child folders in a compact
>   form. In such a form, single child folders will be compressed in a
>   combined tree element. Useful for Java package structures, for
>   example.
>
> Setting `explorer.compactFolders` controls this behavior. By default,
>   this setting is turned on.

So `"explorer.compactFolders": false,` will disable the feature.

[image: compact folders demo]

Comment: Where to put `"explorer.compactFolders": false`? In which file? In which line?

Comment: @parsecer That is a setting and goes in your `settings.json` file and go anywhere inside that file.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings for more.

Comment: @parsecer as for me, the most convenient way to open JSON settings file is to open the commands palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and type "settings json". The list will offer you few options from which you can select the file you like. I have such settings files: "Default", "User" and "Workspace".