# vscode disable empty folders (parent/child folders) merge/collapse/inline

Tags: visual-studio-code

If child folder is empty, vscode get them merged like on screenshot. Is there an option to disable it? It's confusing and harder to use for me.

[image]

Comment: It's a horrible default

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Disable/uncheck `Explorer: Compact Folders` in your settings.

Related info from release notes: [Is there a way to unify single-folder folders in vs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53726587/is-there-a-way-to-unify-single-folder-folders-in-vs-code/56655326#56655326)

Comment: Also, if you use JSON settings, this property is `"explorer.compactFolders": false`.

Comment: I am wondering who thought that was a good idea in the first place...

Comment: It should be disable by default, because this is really annoying!

Comment: Incredibly annoying feature

Comment: @Mirko for Java packages it _is_ really useful, but I agree that it should be disabled by default

Answer (score 58):

In VsCode on MAC go to Code (top left hand corner)

1. Select `Preferences`
2. then `Settings`
3. then Search for `compact folders`
4. Uncheck the

[image]

Answer (score 13):

In VsCode on WINDOWS go to File (top left hand corner)

1. Select `Preferences`
2. then `Settings` (or you can simply press `Ctrl/Cmd+,`)
3. then search for `Compact Folders`
4. Unckeck the option