# Is this a bug or feature in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

As the image show when I added a subfolder "User" then it looked like this?
Is this expected?

[image]

Comment: Yes, thats expected.

Comment: feature, not showing subdirs in a tree if there's only one.

Comment: The reason for this is? What's the problem with a normal tree-view?

Comment: Dunno, ask Microsoft. The guess is that they thought making you open a folder just to then inevitably have to also open the one subfolder that it contains was extra work/space used, and they wanted to optimise that out. But this will amount only to speculation on SO.

Comment: It is easily controlled by a setting, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59415357/836330  Some frameworks have deeply nested directory structures  - their users requested the feature.

Comment: github does a similar thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is a feature in VS code.