# Inner folders are shown side by side in Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image: Visual Studio folders]

So my folders suddenly started to look like this in VS code. How do I make it look like as normal again?

Comment: Thats default view for a single folder you probably can turn off this option in settings

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59415357/836330 for how to turn that off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They appear like that when the folder only have one sub-folder. Once you add more folders, it will start appearing as usual.

Comment: Indeed it does, thank you man. I should have added components before I ask question

Answer (score 4):

Disable "Compact folders" in settings