# What does the "/" mean in VSCode file formatting?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I have started using VSCode and was wondering what the `/` meant when I click on a file (see attached screenshot). Is it simply the full path of the file that I've clicked on? Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It means that the top folder has only one folder inside

Comment: Ok, and all the results shown under `@metamask/eth-sig-util` are actually inside that one folder right?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59415299/vscode-disable-empty-folders-parent-child-folders-merge-collapse-inline/59415357?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C48.5934#59415357 if you want to disable that style of showing folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means sub folder inside main folder you have created

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be referring to the feature where a folder with a single subfolder are shown on the same line.

For example, let's consider the following structure:

```
X/
├─ a/
│  ├─ a1/
│  │  └- a1.txt
│  └- a2/
│     └- a2.txt
└ b/
  └- b1/
      └- b1.txt
```

Since `b1` is the only folder under `b` the explorer window will show `b` and `b1` on a single line:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

eth-sig-util is child folder of metamask folder which is parent.
To access child we have to use '/' after parent folder.